# Rotating a two dimensional array by 90 degrees

Tags: algorithm, matrix, multidimensional-array, rotation

I am studying this piece of code on rotating an NxN matrix; I have traced the program countless times, and I sort of understand how the actual rotation happens. It basically rotates the corners first and the elements after the corners in a clockwise direction. I just do not understand a couple of lines, and the code is still not "driven home" in my brain, so to speak. Please help. I am rotating it 90 degrees, given a 4x4 matrix as my tracing example.

```
[1][2][3][4] 
[5][6][7][8]
[9][0][1][2]
[3][4][5][6]
```

becomes

```
[3][9][5][1]
[4][0][6][2]
[5][1][7][3]
[6][2][8][4]
```

---

```
public static void rotate(int[][] matrix, int n){
  for(int layer=0; layer < n/2; ++layer) {
     int first=layer; //It moves from the outside in. 
     int last=n-1-layer; //<--This I do not understand  
     for(int i=first; i<last;++i){
       int offset=i-first; //<--A bit confusing for me

       //save the top left of the matrix 
       int top = matrix[first][i];

       //shift left to top; 
       matrix[first][i]=matrix[last-offset][first]; 
       /*I understand that it needs
        last-offset so that it will go up the column in the matrix,
       and first signifies it's in the first column*/

       //shift bottom to left 
       matrix[last-offset][first]=matrix[last][last-offset];
        /*I understand that it needs
        last-offset so that the number decreases and it may go up the column (first 
        last-offset) and left (latter). */

       //shift right to bottom
       matrix[last][last-offset]=matrix[i][last];
        /*I understand that it i so that in the next iteration, it moves down 
        the column*/        



       //rightmost top corner
        matrix[i][last]=top;
       }
   }

}
```

Answer (score 9):

It's easier to understand an algorithm like this if you draw a diagram, so I made a quick pic in Paint to demonstrate for a 5x5 matrix :D

The outer `for(int layer=0; layer < n/2; ++layer)` loop iterates over the layers from outside to inside. The outer layer (layer 0) is depicted by coloured elements. Each layer is effectively a square of elements requiring rotation. For n = 5, *layer* will take on values from 0 to 1 as there are 2 layers since we can ignore the centre element/layer which is unaffected by rotation. *first* and *last* refer to the first and last rows/columns of elements for a layer; e.g. layer 0 has elements from Row/Column *first = 0* to *last = 4* and layer 1 from Row/Column 1 to 3.

Then for each layer/square, the inner `for(int i=first; i<last;++i)` loop rotates it by rotating 4 elements in each iteration. *Offset* represents how far along the sides of the square we are. For our 5x5 below, we first rotate the red elements (offset = 0), then yellow (offset = 1), then green and blue. Arrows 1-5 demonstrate the 4-element rotation for the red elements, and 6+ for the rest which are performed in the same fashion. Note how the 4-element rotation is essentially a 5-assignment circular swap with the first assignment temporarily putting aside an element. The `//save the top left of the matrix` comment for this assignment is misleading since matrix[first][i] isn't necessarily the top left of the matrix or even the layer for that matter. Also, note that the row/column indexes of elements being rotated are sometimes proportional to *offset* and sometimes proportional to its inverse, *last - offset*.

We move along the sides of the outer layer (delineated by first=0 and last=4) in this manner, then move onto the inner layer (first = 1 and last = 3) and do the same thing there. Eventually, we hit the centre and we're done.

[image]

Answer (score 6):

This trigger a WTF. The easiest way to rotate a matrix in place is by

- first transposing the matrix (swap M[i,j] with M[j,i])
- then swapping M[i,j] with M[i, nColumns - j]

When matrices are column-major, the second operation is swapping columns, and hence has good data locality properties. If the matrix is row major, then first permute rows, and then transpose.

Comment: I agree that it's an easier method, but wouldn't it be much less efficient for small matrices? Transposing the matrix moves the elements to the correct row, but the wrong column, which requires later correction. The OP's algorithm moves the elements to the correct row and column on the first go (fewer assignments in total). I'm ignoring locality in this comparison since it isn't a problem for small matrices. For large matrices, we might want to alter the ordering of assignments in the OP's algorithm, and optimise the transposition in this algorithm.

Comment: @Nathan: Both methods perform the same number of memory loads and memory assignments (remember the swap temporary will be usually a register, as well as `top` in OP's code). This one is simple and readable, and probably more efficient than the proposed one which does not address data contiguously.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a recursive way of solving this:

// rotating a 2 D array (mXn) by 90 degrees

```
public void rotateArray(int[][] inputArray) {
    System.out.println("Input Array: ");
    print2D(inputArray);
    rotateArray(inputArray, 0, 0, inputArray.length - 1,
            inputArray[0].length - 1);
    System.out.println("\n\nOutput Array: ");
    print2D(inputArray);

}

public void rotateArray(int[][] inputArray, int currentRow,
        int currentColumn, int lastRow, int lastColumn) {

    // condition to come out of recursion.
    // if all rows are covered or all columns are covered (all layers
    // covered)
    if (currentRow >= lastRow || currentColumn >= lastColumn)
        return;
    // rotating the corner elements first
    int top = inputArray[currentRow][currentColumn];
    inputArray[currentRow][currentColumn] = inputArray[lastRow][currentColumn];
    inputArray[lastRow][currentColumn] = inputArray[lastRow][lastColumn];
    inputArray[lastRow][lastColumn] = inputArray[currentRow][lastColumn];
    inputArray[currentRow][lastColumn] = top;

    // clockwise rotation of remaining elements in the current layer
    for (int i = currentColumn + 1; i < lastColumn; i++) {
        int temp = inputArray[currentRow][i];
        inputArray[currentRow][i] = inputArray[lastRow - i][currentColumn];
        inputArray[lastRow - i][currentColumn] = inputArray[lastRow][lastColumn
                - i];
        inputArray[lastRow][lastColumn - i] = inputArray[currentRow + i][lastColumn];
        inputArray[currentRow + i][lastColumn] = temp;
    }

    // call recursion on remaining layers
    rotateArray(inputArray, ++currentRow, ++currentColumn, --lastRow,
            --lastColumn);
}
```